# error in import in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the structure in Python 3:

```
my_module/
    my_module/
        any_name.py
    tests/
        tests.py
```

Then, I am trying to use in tests.py:

```
from my_module.any_name import my_class
```

And I am receiving the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Where are your `__init__` files?

Comment: python3 tests/tests.py

Comment: I do not create any __init__ file. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 3):

First, it's pretty confusing to have `my_module` and `my_module/my_module`, but let's ignore that.

In order for `my_module` to work, the outer `my_module` has to be on your `sys.path`.

So, if you do this:

```
$ cd tests
$ python tests.py
```

… then your `sys.path` will just by your usual path, plus `my_module/tests`. It won't include `my_module`, so you can't find `my_module/my_module` anywhere.

Ways around this include:

- Have a top-level `test.py` that does `from tests import tests.py` and `tests.run()`.
- Run you code as `python -m tests.tests` from the top-level `my_module` directory, instead of running it as `python tests.py` from `my_module/tests`.
- Have `tests/tests.py` insert `os.path.join(__path__, '../my_module`) into `sys.path` manually.
- Use `setuptools`/`pkg_resources` instead of trying to do everything manually.
- Do the hacky old-style thing described [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#namespace-packages-today). (You really don't want to do this unless you need to be compatible with Python 2.7 or 3.2 or old `distribute`/`distutils` versions of `pkg_resources`.)

Comment: Thank you! Run python -m tests.tests fix my test. But now other importations in my code broken. When I use import any_name in other file in my_project I need to put .any_name and when I run my program 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'